# Getting json response using POST Request using scrapy python

Tags: python, json, post, scrapy, request

I am trying to getting the data using post request from this [website](https://www.sarvadajewels.com/diamond-search/?selected-diamond=round/#/). I have found the post url in that website but I am not getting the same response using scrapy.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import request
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import json

class CodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'code'
    allowed_domains = ['code.comcom']
    start_urls = ['https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx']

    def start_requests(self): 
        form_data = {"request":{"header":{"raplink_access_key":"e7d7d61946804c579d02dab565371113","domain":"www.sarvadajewels.com"},"body":{"search_type":"white","shapes":["round"],"size_from":0.1,"size_to":100,"color_from":"D","color_to":"M","clarity_from":"IF","clarity_to":"I1","cut_from":"Excellent","cut_to":"Poor","polish_from":"Excellent","polish_to":"Poor","symmetry_from":"Excellent","symmetry_to":"Poor","labs":[],"fancy_colors":[],"price_total_from":0,"price_total_to":7428404930,"page_number":2,"page_size":"60","sort_by":"price","sort_direction":"asc","currency_code":"INR"}}}
        request_body = json.dumps(form_data)
        yield scrapy.Request('https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx',
                            method="POST",
                            body=request_body,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},callback=self.parse )

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('test.json', 'w') as file:
            file.write(str(response.body)
```

and I am facing this error:

```
{'response': {'header': {'error_code': 1001, 'error_message': 'Invalid format'
        }, 'body': {}
    }



IS there anyway to get this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an incorrect header:

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
```

it should be:

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Complete code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import request
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import json

class CodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'code'
    allowed_domains = ['code.comcom']
    start_urls = ['https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx']

    def start_requests(self): 
        form_data = {"request":{"header":{"raplink_access_key":"e7d7d61946804c579d02dab565371113","domain":"www.sarvadajewels.com"},"body":{"search_type":"white","shapes":["round"],"size_from":0.1,"size_to":100,"color_from":"D","color_to":"M","clarity_from":"IF","clarity_to":"I1","cut_from":"Excellent","cut_to":"Poor","polish_from":"Excellent","polish_to":"Poor","symmetry_from":"Excellent","symmetry_to":"Poor","labs":[],"fancy_colors":[],"price_total_from":0,"price_total_to":7428404930,"page_number":2,"page_size":"60","sort_by":"price","sort_direction":"asc","currency_code":"INR"}}}
        request_body = json.dumps(form_data)
        yield scrapy.Request('https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx',
                            method="POST",
                            body=request_body,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},callback=self.parse )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield json.loads(response.text)
```

Also, scrapy supports to write a file in different formats with the items obtained using `-o` flag. So you can use it instead of python `write`, try:

```
scrapy runspider <spider_name> -o test.json
```

or

```
scrapy crawl code -o test.json
```

Comment: Now data are coming but I also want to get data from json

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have done it. Thank you for rectification

Comment: If this answer is correct, consider to upvote and mark it as answered.